# User entering a sentence in an input and Python picking out keywords and getting it from CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I have a task to create a code with a CSV file. I have to create a code and after I run it, the user must enter the answer in a sentence and Python must then pick out keywords from the sentence and cross-reference from the CSV file and give the user an answer.
I have created a code which asks:

***Which game(s) would you like to know the price of?***

The user must write an answer which could possibly say:

***The games which I would like to know the prices of are: FarCry4 GTA 5***

Python must then pick out the words **FarCry4** and **GTA5**. It must then tell the price of the games after importing the CSV file but I can't do this because Python picks every word in Python and tells the price. Please help.

**CODE:**

```
import csv

games = []#subjects
howmuchitcosts = []#teachers

with open('gamesandprices.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile)

    for row in readCSV:
        games.append(row[0])
        howmuchitcosts.append(row[1])


what_game = input("Which game(s) would you like to find out the price of?: ")

what_game = what_game.split(' ')

if len(what_game) > 6:
    print("Too many games. Only type in 6 games.")

for one_game in what_game:

    theprice = []
    gamedex = 0

    while True:

        try:
            gamedex = games.index(one_game, gamedex)
        except:
            break 

        theprice.append(howmuchitcosts[gamedex])

        gamedex += 1 

    theprice = ', '.join(theprice)

    print("The price of", one_game, "is", theprice)
```

P.S: I used this code from another question which was asked in StackOverflow from another topic.

***When I enter a sentence which is this:***
    I want to know the price of GTA5 and FarCry4

**And when I press *ENTER*, this comes up:**

```
Too many games. Only type in 6 games.
The price of I is 
The price of want is 
The price of to is 
The price of know is 
The price of the is 
The price of price is 
The price of of is 
The price of GTA5 is £30.99
The price of and is 
The price of FarCry4 is £40.99
```

But I want python to pick up only GTA5 and FarCry4 and tell the price of those games, not the whole sentence.

This is from another topic as he is working on the same code :)

Comment: Just make a list of the games and match the input to the names. That should do.

Comment: Your main problem will be derivations in the user input. For instance, `FarCry 5` is not the same as `FarCry5` or even `farcry 5`. You will need some sort of error margin and similarity checks. Google 'python string similarity comparison' or Google `Levenshtein distance`

Comment: Adding `if one_game in games:` right after `for one_game in what_game:` fixed it for me.

I think the code was not meant to have a complete sentence as an input.

Comment: I realise the indentation changes a lot of things with the two last lines.

If you include `theprice = ', '.join(theprice)` and `print("The price of", one_game, "is", theprice)` in the while loop, you only have the two games in the result, but if you don't, you have your current result.

However, the "too many games" will still be there, you need to filter the split with the game list.

Comment: Morb and Torxed, can you show me the code which worked for you guys? And yeah, it has to have a full sentence as an input and then it must pick keywords from the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the code that reads your csv to produce a dictionary, then simply lookup the word from the input. If the word is in the dictionary, it means you have a price for that game; and so only print the output then:

```
import csv

price_list = {} # this is an empty dictionary

with open('gamesandprices.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in readCSV:
        price_list[row[0]] = row[1]

what_game = input("Which game(s) would you like to find out the price of?: ")
what_game = what_game.split(' ')

# Now what we want to do, is for each word in the input, check if it
# exists in our dictionary. If it does exist, it must be the name of
# a game, so we need to know its price.

# We also want to make sure we limit the number of games in one
# request to 6 games. To find out how many games the person entered,
# lets filter all the words and collect those words (and prices)
# that are games in a list.

# The long way of writing this is:
# results = [] - this is an empty list
# for word in what_game:
#    if word in price_list: 
#        results.append(word, price_list[word])

results = [(game, price_list[game]) for game in what_game if game in price_list]

if len(results) > 6:
    print('Please ask prices for a maximum of 6 games')
else:
    for game, price in results:
        print('The price of {} is {}'.format(game, price))
```

Comment: It works, but there's still the `Too many games. Only type in 6 games.` sentence. Sorry, cmd is crap for copy/paste.

Comment: Yeah, but now it actually does what it says on the tin.

Comment: Burkhan, THANK YOU!!!! Also can you explain how the code works if you have time? I want to know how the code works and what the dictionary and format(game, pric)) does. Marked answer correct.